# Generate rand hash by md5 and sha1

Tags: php, encryption, random, md5, sha1

i have used

```
md5(sha1(rand()))
```

this will give me 2 levels of encryption and output hash with 32 length like

cbc7a20f14eab9262efe0adb21074d0a

but how i can let hash be 255 length (for example) ?

Comment: This won't do you any good. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You are probably looking for [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/uniqid)

Comment: Well, in order to make it 255 hexadecimal characters long, it would have to be 1020 bits in size, so you would need to find a hashing algorithm that generates a hash of that size.

Comment: @SLaks i'm trying to create cron jobs hash with 255 length

Comment: A cryptographic hash of a bad random number doesn't seem useful. What problem are you actually trying to solve? Do you really want a hash? Do you want a cryptographic random number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatever you're doing just stop it now.

Calling the same or different cryptographic functions repeatedly ***does not do anything like give you multiple levels of encryption***.  If anything, it *weakens* the encryption by making it easier to find a hash collision.

Moreover, neither md5 nor sha-1 are cryptographically secure.

If you're trying to create passwords, use bcrypt or PBKDF2 (and only *once*). Don't forget to use a unique salt and high iteration count.

You may use a KBKDF (key based key derivation function) like the ones specified in NIST SP 800-108 or HKDF to expand the output of bcrypt or PBKDF2 into more bytes. Note however that this does not increase the security level to the number of bytes in the output.

Comment: Pretty strong words on `sha1`.  I beleive most experts still think its secure.  But MAYBE attackable.

Comment: @RichardSchneider Many people say the same thing about `sha1`.  It is apparently on NIST's approved lists, but even they seem to be wary of it: http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/policy.html

Comment: Thanks very much.  You learn something new everyday. I never saw the NIST post and I'm on their mailing list!

Comment: @RichardSchneider - [The PHP documentaion on `sha1`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) clearly states that it shouldn't be used for password hashing: **It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash) for details.**

Comment: @Explosion Pills thank you very much for this information i will take care and never forget this :)

Comment: Expanded your answer, Explosion Pills, hope you don't mind :)

Comment: The strength of SHA-1 or MD5 is quite irrelevant here. Collisions are not relevant for this. The problem is that `rand` sucks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create cryptographic random numbers, anything relying on `rand()` won't do any good. No matter which hash or KDF you throw at it.

Use `mcrypt_create_iv ($size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)` instead, which conventiently has a `$size` parameter, solving your length problem at the same time.